# How do you reload all vim windows at once?

Tags: vim

I have a few files open in vim, in multiple windows. Is there a command like :e that will reload the buffers for all the files I have open? I need this because I sometime alter some of the files with another editor while they are also open in vim.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The `:windo` command does for windows what `:bufdo` does for buffers.  That is:

```
 :windo e
```

should cycle through all visible windows (i.e, not windows on other tabs, if any) and execute the `:e` command.  Likewise:

```
 :bufdo e
```

would cycle through all buffers in the buffer list (i.e., no "hidden" buffers) and execute the same command.

Note that you may have buffers in the buffer list that are not currently displayed in any window.  So whether to use `:windo e` or `:bufdo e` depends on what you want.

Relevant help is here:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#list-repeat

Comment: Similarly `:tabdo e` would reload all windows in all tabs

Comment: Hmm, I haven't tried, but to cover split-window cases wouldn't that require `:tabdo exec 'windo e'`?

Comment: You're right - my bad.  `:tabdo e` only reloads teh first window in each tab. Thanks :) explains why I had trouble yesterday

Comment: I notice that this removes syntax highlighting on some buffers. I had to go to those buffers and manually enter `:e` on each. Is there a way to preserve syntax highlighting? I'm using Vim 8.0 (2016 Sep 12).

Answer (score 11):

Vim will automatically reload buffers that have been changed externally (and don't have unsaved changes) if you set the ['autoread'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autoread') option.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
:bufdo e
```